# Is it possible to get Angular2 as a single JS file?

Tags: angular

I was trying to play around with Angular2 and the first thing I noticed was the lack of a single JS file. Now in addition to Angular you basically have to include each module as well. Even that wouldn't be all that bad, however, the src folder is required for DI and that has a broad-tree structure.

I know questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926666/angular2-is-it-slow) say that they are separated to improve performance. However, for now I could sacrifice that for simplicity. I tried looking into the way it is loaded and it seems as though there is no easy way to just include them all.

I am currently trying to add items to a Plnkr.co project which does not seem to support uploading an entire folder.

Answer (score 2):

The Angular 2 self executing file should help you getting started. It is referenced in the official docs and you can grab it from here:

https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.26/angular2.sfx.dev.js

Note that `alpha.26` is the latest version as of writing this answer. You might want to change that.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Microsoft repo ´ngconf2015demo'